# How to Improve Modal Pop-Up Integration for Settings Page in a Web Application?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a web application where I need to present a "Settings" page as a pop-up over the main content. Currently, I am using an iframe within a modal to display this page. However, the result is not visually appealing and the integration feels clunky. I'm looking for suggestions to improve the user experience and visual integration of this modal pop-up.

Here's my current code:

```js
// Open settings modal
document.getElementById('settings-button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('settingsFrame').src = '/settings';
  document.getElementById('settingsModal').style.display = 'block';
});

// Close modal functionality
var modal = document.getElementById("settingsModal");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-button")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('settingsFrame').src = ''; // Clear the iframe source
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('settingsFrame').src = ''; // Clear the iframe source
  }
}


// Toggle menu visibility
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('showNavMenu');
});

// Open settings page
//<!-- document.getElementById('settings-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
//  window.location.href = 'settings';
//}); -->

// Global variable to keep track of the currently selected taskboard
let currentTaskboard = null;

// Update taskboard functionality
document.getElementById('update-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (!currentTaskboard) {
    alert('Please select a taskboard first.');
    return;
  }

  var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
  fileInput.type = 'file';
  fileInput.accept = '.xlsx';

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('name', currentTaskboard);

    fetch('/upload/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        fetchTaskboardData(currentTaskboard);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  });

  fileInput.click();
});

// Open taskboard selection modal
document.getElementById('open-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  fetch('/list/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(taskboards => {
      populateTaskboardSelector(Object.values(taskboards));
      showModal();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching taskboards:', error);
    });
});

// Populate taskboard selector in modal
function populateTaskboardSelector(taskboards) {
  var selector = document.getElementById('taskboard-selector');
  selector.innerHTML = '';
  taskboards.forEach(taskboard => {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = taskboard;
    option.textContent = taskboard;
    selector.appendChild(option);
  });
}

// Show modal
function showModal() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Close modal functionality
document.querySelector('.close-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
  modal.style.display = 'none';
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
  var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

// Handle taskboard selection from modal
document.getElementById('select-taskboard-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var selectedTaskboard = document.getElementById('taskboard-selector').value;
  if (selectedTaskboard) {
    openTaskboard(selectedTaskboard);
    var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    alert('Please select a taskboard.');
  }
});

// Edit taskboard functionality
document.getElementById('edit-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (!currentTaskboard) {
    alert('Please select a taskboard first.');
    return;
  }
  window.location.href = `/edit?name=${encodeURIComponent(currentTaskboard)}`;
});

// New taskboard functionality
document.getElementById('new-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('new-taskboard-form').style.display = 'block';
});

// Submit new taskboard
document.getElementById('submit-new-taskboard').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var taskboardName = document.getElementById('new-taskboard-name').value;
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('new-taskboard-file');
  var file = fileInput.files[0];

  if (!taskboardName || !file) {
    alert('Please enter a taskboard name and select a file.');
    return;
  }

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('name', taskboardName);
  formData.append('file', file);

  fetch('/create', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Taskboard created:', data);
      document.getElementById('new-taskboard-form').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('new-taskboard-name').value = '';
      fileInput.value = '';
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});

// Function to fetch and display taskboard data
function fetchTaskboardData(taskboardName) {
  console.log('Fetching data for:', taskboardName); // Debug log
  fetch(`/get/?name=${encodeURIComponent(taskboardName)}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Data received:', data); // Debug log
      var taskboardGrid = document.getElementById('taskboard-grid');
      taskboardGrid.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content

      // Check if data is an object and not an array
      if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null && !Array.isArray(data)) {
        Object.values(data).forEach(createCard); // Iterate over object values
      } else {
        console.error('Unexpected data format:', data);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching taskboard data:', error);
    });
}

// Function to create a card for each task
function createCard(row) {
  console.log('Creating card for:', row); // Debug log
  var card = document.createElement('div');
  card.className = 'task-card';

  Object.keys(row).forEach(key => {
    if (row[key] !== null && row[key] !== undefined) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.textContent = `${key}: ${row[key]}`;
      card.appendChild(p);
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('taskboard-grid').appendChild(card); // Append card to taskboard grid
}

// Open taskboard function
function openTaskboard(taskboardName) {
  currentTaskboard = taskboardName;
  fetchTaskboardData(taskboardName);
}

// DOMContentLoaded event listener
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const taskboardName = urlParams.get('name');
  if (taskboardName) {
    openTaskboard(taskboardName);
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

header {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  /* Ensure nav is positioned for absolute positioning of children */
  padding-left: 0;
}

nav h1 {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #007bff;
  /* Set the background color to blue */
  position: relative;
  /* Ensure relative positioning for the nav h1 */
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  margin-left: -40px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

nav h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Makes sure the transformation applies properly */
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  /* Opposite skew to the button's skew */
}

nav .hamburger {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  /* Change the color of the hamburger icon to white for better visibility */
  padding-left: 150px;
  transform: skewX(0deg);
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  /* Position to the right of the nav h1 */
  transform: scaleX(0);
  /* Initially collapsed along the X axis */
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 350ms ease-in-out;
  /* Animate the transform property */
  background-color: #222;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Optional: Add a shadow for better visibility */
}

.showNavMenu {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  /* Expand to full width */
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  /* Change to block for vertical list */
  padding: 5px;
}

.button-blue {
  background: #007bff;
  /* Assuming a solid blue; replace with gradient if needed */
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: -15px;
  /* Space between buttons */
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  /* Smooth transition for hover effect */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* If the text should be uppercase as in the screenshot */
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Adjust this to align the nav items as in the screenshot */
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
}


/* Style for the hamburger icon */

nav .hamburger {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  /* Change the color of the hamburger icon to white for better visibility */
}


/* You might also want to style the <ul> element to have padding and margin 0 */

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  /* To align the buttons horizontally */
}


/* Style for the <li> elements to remove list styles and margins */

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li button.button-blue:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  /* Keep the background color blue on hover */
}

.button-blue:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #0056b3, #004291);
  box-shadow: 0 2px #002b5e;
  transform: translateY(2px) skewX(-20deg);
  /* Add skew transformation here as well */
}

#new-taskboard-form {
  display: none;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

#new-taskboard-form input[type="text"],
#new-taskboard-form input[type="file"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#new-taskboard-form button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#new-taskboard-form button:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

#new-taskboard-form input[type="text"]::placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto;
  /* 5% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  border-radius: 8px;
  /* Optional: Rounded corners */
}

.close-button {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close-button:hover,
.close-button:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.taskboard-selector {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Aligns items on opposite ends */
  align-items: center;
}

.button-blue span {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Makes sure the transformation applies properly */
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  /* Opposite skew to the button's skew */
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.close-button {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close-button:hover,
.close-button:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1><span>My New Taskboard</span><span class="hamburger">&#9776;</span></h1>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><button id="update-button" class="button-blue"><span>Update</span></button></li>
      <li><button id="edit-button" class="button-blue"><span>Edit</span></button></li>
      <li><button id="open-button" class="button-blue"><span>Open</span></button></li>
      <li><button id="new-button" class="button-blue"><span>New</span></button></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <button id="settings-button" class="button-blue"><span>Settings</span></button>
  <!-- Moved outside of the nav, into the header -->
</header>
<main>

  <section class="taskboard-grid" id="taskboard-grid">
    <!-- Task cards will be dynamically added here -->
  </section>

  <!-- Hidden form for creating a new taskboard -->
  <div id="new-taskboard-form">
    <input type="text" id="new-taskboard-name" placeholder="Enter Taskboard Name">
    <input type="file" id="new-taskboard-file" accept=".xlsx">
    <button id="submit-new-taskboard">Create Taskboard</button>
  </div>
</main>

<div id="taskboard-selection-modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
    <h2>Select a Taskboard</h2>
    <select id="taskboard-selector" class="taskboard-selector">
      <!-- Taskboard options will be dynamically populated here -->
    </select>
    <button id="select-taskboard-button" class="button-blue">Open Taskboard</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Settings Modal -->
<div id="settingsModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
    <iframe id="settingsFrame" src="" style="width:100%; height:80vh;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm experiencing is that the iframe doesn't blend well with the rest of the modal, and it feels detached from the overall user experience of the application. I'm looking for a way to make this integration smoother, potentially without using an iframe, while still keeping the "Settings" page as a separate entity that can be loaded into the modal.

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

This is how it should looks:

[image]

Also it should uses the `/settings` endpoint because of the backend.

Comment: Perhaps add a second snippet with the modal HTML - and potentially and "other" so we can combine them with the current snippet as a functional group.  It might also help to reduce this original snippet to JUST the HTML and JavaScript related to better meet the guidance from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and from here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  As it is now the snippet is pretty much a "code wall"